# Spring MCV - Removing element for DOM not resulting null because int

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, dom, model-view-controller

Person Object

```
public class Person {
    public Person() {

    }

    @Id
    @Column(name="person_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int personId;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="tb_person_phonelist", joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="person_id") }, inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="phonelist_id", referencedColumnName="phonelist_id") })
    private List<PhoneList> phoneList = LazyList.decorate(new ArrayList<PhoneList>(), FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(PhoneList.class));

//getter & setter
}
```

PhoneList Object

```
public class PhoneList {
    public PhoneList() {

    }

    @Id
    @Column(name="phonelist_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)   
    private int phoneListId;
    @Column(name="provider")
    private String providerName;
//getter & setter
}
```

So far I'm successfull to load, add new, and edit in the project. but for deletion I'm still confused. So far what I do is by deleting the DOM using
jquery (Please note that the scenario of deletion can't be postback to server, so i need to use javascript to manipulate the object via DOM manipulation)

let say the generated bind is

```
<tr><td><input name="personEntity.phoneList[1].phoneListId" id="personEntity.phoneList1.phoneListId" type="hidden" abp="257" value="24"/><input name="personEntity.phoneList[1].providerName" class="form-control" id="inputProviderName" type="text" placeholder="Provider Name" abp="268" value=""/></td></tr>
```

so what do is just

```
$('tr').remove();
```

assuming that removing the DOM makes the object will be changed depend on the latest DOM.

but when i submit/post into the controller, the phoneList object is not empty, I suspect it because phoneListId is type integer, which it will never be null.

is there any way to make it null?

Answer (score 0):

It never should be empty what here happening is you are using here container must be creating some model object here ,by which you are getting your form data.

so its first creating a object and initialize its properties to default values and than its passing it to container

that's why its not empty you need to check if phone list is having value 0 which is integer have default 0 values you should delete it .